# Как скомпилировать TOR.exe на windows 7, чтоб был доступ к файлу конфигурации or.h?

Tags: windows, компиляция, tor

У меня есть tor.exe, хочу понять как "привязать" к нему файл конфигурации or.h, чтоб была возможность более тонко настраивать соединения

Comment: Никак. Забудьте про exe и собирайте тор из исходников.

Comment: https://github.com/arlolra/tor это и есть исходники? нужно из этого всего и собрать exe? чтоб запустить его хотя бы